# Preparation for Undergraduate Mathematical Thinking

Tags: soft-question

I have a soft question.

I am currently finishing up my second year in undergraduate mathematics. When I look at the "unanswered" section here on the MSE, I seldom understand the questions being asked.

In general, I feel way behind other university students, especially those from other countries. In the US, our standard public education is quite brutal for mathematics.

What can I do to feel more prepared and begin to think like a mathematician? I seem to work hard instead of smart. In other words, I generally lack creativity and ingenuity in solving problems.

Comment: Mathematics is a vast subject. Even as a second year undergraduate, you will only understand a small fraction of all of the mathematics that exits.

Comment: Maybe it's already clear to you, but I would like to point out that the questions here vary drastically in mathematical level, and some of them are basically research level. It is 100% normal for an undergrad student to not understand a lot of questions on this site.

Comment: ... and the unanswered question list biases **heavily** towards the harder questions (otherwise they would have been answered or closed and/or deleted).

Comment: @CaptainLama Do you have any tips on improving mathematical thinking ability/*creativity*?